# Android Video View Thumbnail?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have the video which is stored under specific folder in sdcard. Currently i have the path as only parameter(Ex:"sdcard/test/sample.mp4"), by using url alone is it possible to retrieve the thumbnail of the image.

I also want to show the video preview display in android ,any one provide some example to do this thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ThumbnailUtils is an easy-to use API for generating thumbnails from arbitrary filesystem paths. It is available in API level 8.

Check out [ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Comment: This works, but how to get the thumbnail of custom resolution? I can see only two resolutions MINI_KIND and MICRO_KIND.

Comment: You can get a size larger than you need and then resize using BitmapFactory.

Comment: I have got it using ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail() function. Thanks

Comment: Oh cool! I didn't know you could use that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: it is not working fine for me i got following error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.media.ThumbnailUtils.

Comment: what api level are you on? This is Froyo and above.

Comment: But how to set it on the VideoView? I mean `mVideoView.setBackgroundDrawable` method is deprecated.