# VideoView: Fullscreen on doubleTap

Tags: android, android-videoview

Basically, what I want to do in my application is displaying a video.

The best tool to achieve this goal seem to be a VideoView.

So I used this code:

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoview" android:layout_width="50dip" android:layout_height="50dip"></VideoView>
```

and in my Activity:

```
 VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);
 videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
 videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.blabla.blabla/" + R.raw.blabla));
 videoHolder.requestFocus(); 
 videoHolder.start();
```

and that do the trick.

Unfortunately, I was expecting having a preview (thumbnail) of the video in my layout by default

So , I removed the videoHolder.start(); command, but I can only get a blackscreen. The video start when tapping on an invisible zone...

**First question**

Is that possible to display a preview of the video in the VideoView before starting it?

**Second question**

I wuld like to display the video on Fullscreen when double tapping the webview, How can I achieve this?

Thank a lot for any help / link / suggestion

Comment: can you catch the double click on the webview and start a new activity that is full screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get video thumbnails using [ThumbnailUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html):

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

I haven't really seen apps toggle into fullscreen before. I'm actually not sure if it can be done (especially for a `VideoView`). However, you might have some luck with one of these methods:

1. Holding the `VideoView` in a `FrameLayout` and then changing its layout parameters.
2. Overlaying the `VideoView` via `Window#addContentView`.
3. Hiding (via `Visibility.GONE`) your other views and allowing the `VideoView` to expand its layout area.

Comment: Seem that I have the same issue than this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321853/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-media-thumbnailutils

This error is also described after your own answer ( that I should have read before lol) posted by user555806: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233317/android-video-view-thumbnail

Cannot get the Thumbnail.. I will try to investigate..

Comment: You have to be targetting android-8 (Froyo) or later in order to access this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VideoView.seekTo(milliseconds) as an alternative, let say 1 second (1000 milliseconds). Provided that the video clip after 1 second does have an image, like some videos starts from blank screen then "fade-in" (lack of better word) to a scene would more often gives you a black screen with 1 second. You can call this under VideoView.onPrepared(). This one i use when the video is on a web server.