# How To toggle FullScreen with VideoView Android

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I am using video view for live streaming, and I want to make this `VideoView` to toggle *fullscreen* and back to small screen like `MXPlayer` or `YouTube` players do without stopping the streams.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ad_container"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_annouc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:lines="1"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scroll_annouc"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="270dp"
                android:background="@android:color/black" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/error_overlay"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="270dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:background="@color/red_trans"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/error_text"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/player"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/media_controller"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:background="@color/black_trans" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_playpause"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_pause"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:padding="@dimen/five_dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/external_player"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:text="Use External Player"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/content_size"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btn_fullscreen"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                        android:padding="@dimen/five_dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/enter_fullscreen" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/two_dp"
                android:background="@color/app_blue" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/loading_txt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/two_dp"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/two_dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/content_size"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/one_dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/one_dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/channel_links_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/one_dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontal_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/viewsContainer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/one_dp"
                android:background="@color/light_grey" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Everything is working fine like streaming videos and all but I am unable to make this `VideoView` to go to *landscape* and show the video in *fullscreen*. I have tried googling it but all the examples I have found are not working for me at the moment. So please tell me how it is possible to toggle *fullscreen*.
Thanks.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640025/videoview-fullscreen-on-doubletap

Comment: this is my example: https://github.com/vuhung3990/sampleVideoFullscreen, it will fullscreen when landscape

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What i have done is that i created a CustomVideoView which extends VideoView like this:

```
public class CustomVideoView extends VideoView {

private int measuredWidth = 0;
private int measuredHeight = 0;

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void setNewDimension(int width, int height) {
    this.measuredHeight = height;
    this.measuredWidth = width;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
}
}//end class
```

Then on my player activity, i implemented this on fullscreen button's onclick:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    player.setNewDimension(metrics.widthPixels, metrics.heightPixels);
    player.getHolder().setFixedSize(metrics.heightPixels,
            metrics.widthPixels);
    player.setLayoutParams(params);
```

so with this my problem was solved. Hope it will solve others problem as well.

**NOTE**: I'm sorry for not giving anybody credits as i forgot the links i found on google which lead me to make a suitable solution for myself.

Comment: i m doing same but the issue is i have another linearlayout on top of my videoview and that layout is align parent bottom-----> true  but once my orienatation is landscape .... then video should take match parent height and width and layout should on top of vide view should adjust on bottom  but the layout is not working perfectly how to resolve this ?

Comment: @Erum well you can create a wrapper layout for both videoview and your linearlayout and then change the params of that wrapper layout on orientation change

Comment: i have done same .... but video view is not taking full screen  height in case of landscape thats why issue arise @awaistoor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651695/video-not-taking-full-screen-in-landscape-mode-using-videoview-android @awaistoor here is my issue

Comment: @Erum check my answer on your question.

Comment: `The method setNewDimension(int, int) is undefined for the type VideoView` **How can i solve this problem** @awaistoor & @Erum

Comment: @AovinMahmud dont use this function .. just set the layoutParams to the videoview.

Comment: @awaistoor thx my problem is solved.I want to add with u in facebook. Can u please give ur Fb name? it's **emergency**.

Comment: the same username i have here :)

Comment: Cannot resolve player, please help me, I really need this

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 please tell me what's your issue?

Comment: @awaistoor I can't figure what the variable player stand for in this answer

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 `player` variable was of `CustomVideoView` object

Answer (score 2):

To make the video play in full screen you have to create separate activity like below .
The Half screen activity is -

```
    public class HalfScreen extends Activity {
        Button fullbtn;
        VideoView videoView = null;
        final int REQUEST_CODE = 5000;
        // "https://www.youtube.com/embed/olsO7UJemhE";
        final String videoToPlay = "http://bffmedia.com/bigbunny.mp4";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.half);
            videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoViewhalf);
            final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            fullbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfullScreen);

            Uri video = Uri.parse(videoToPlay);
            videoView.setVideoURI(video);
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    videoView.requestFocus();
                    videoView.start();
                }
            });

            fullbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent videointent = new Intent(HalfScreen.this,
                            FullScreen.class);
                    videointent.putExtra("currenttime",
                            videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                    videointent.putExtra("Url", videoToPlay);
                    startActivityForResult(videointent, REQUEST_CODE);

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (data.hasExtra("currenttime")) {
                    int result = data.getExtras().getInt("currenttime", 0);
                    if (result > 0) {
                        if (null != videoView) {
                            videoView.start();
                            videoView.seekTo(result);
                            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 


//Now the full screen activity

     public class FullScreen extends Activity {
            Button btn;
            VideoView videoView = null;
            int currenttime = 0;
            String Url="";
            private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if (null != extras) {
                    currenttime = extras.getInt("currenttime", 0);
                    Url=extras.getString("Url");
                }
                setContentView(R.layout.full);
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
                videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoViewfull);
                MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
                mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

                Uri video = Uri.parse(Url);
                videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                videoView.setVideoURI(video);
                videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        videoView.start();
                        videoView.seekTo(currenttime);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void finish() {
                Intent data = new Intent();
                data.putExtra("currenttime", videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                super.finish();
            }
        }

//To make the video full screen use below layout
full.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff99cc"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoViewfull"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </VideoView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: basically im streaming live channels in that video view and i have tried this solution but when i go from small screen to full, the streaming start reloading and that i dont want

Comment: yes @awaistoor  this is the main  issue in case of differnt layouts

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but I just write this for other mates.

just add this line to your manifest activity to avoid reloading video

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

hope it helps

Comment: try to make views GONE in full screen to make layout full screen