# Video not taking full screen in landscape mode for some devices using videoview in android

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-videoview

My videoview is working fine in portrait mode but in landscape it does not fit in full screen( i do not want to use layout-land). I am trying to change views programmatically but this is not working as expected. I tried to get the resolution of the device using below code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
WindowManager wm =(WindowManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
height = metrics.heightPixels 
width =  metrics.widthPixels
```

Testing on the devices with resolution 1080 * 1920 the value i am getting for height and width is 1080 and 1776 respectively. (For some devices I get correct values and videoview works fine in both orientations)

I am facing the same problem which has been asked in the below link-

[video not taking full screen in landscape mode using videoview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651695/video-not-taking-full-screen-in-landscape-mode-using-videoview-android)

Comment: Did you try the answers provided in the question you mentioned?

Comment: yes but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using this code.

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            );
    private void enterFullScreen(){
            this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            mVideoView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            mVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }

    private void exitFullScreen(){
              this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                mVideoView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
                isFullScreen = false;
                mFullScreen.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                    layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                    layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                    layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                    layoutParams.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
                }else {
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM,0);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,0);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,0);
                    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT,0);
                }
                mFullScreen.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        enter code here`enter code here`
                mVideoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
```